# Picard’s uniqueness and existence theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to ask, where does the number $ b/M $ come from in the conditions required for there to be existence of solution

When they say:: $\alpha = \min( a, b/M )$

---

> **Theorem:** $R=\{(x,y):|x−x_0|≤a,|y−y_0|≤b\}$. Then the IVP $y'=f(x,y)$,  $y(x_0)=y_0$ has an unique solution in the interval $|x−x_0|≤α=\min(a,b/M)$ where $M=\max_{(x,y)∈ R}|f(x,y)|$.

Comment: Post the version of the theorem you're looking at, along with the proof you're looking at. This looks meaningless as a standalone.

Comment: The $b,M$ come from the alphabet.

Comment: R={(x,y):|x−x0|≤a,|y−y0|≤b}
.Then the IVP y′=f(x,y),y(x0)=y0
 has an unique solution in the interval |x−x0|≤h=min(a,b/M)
 where M=MAX(x,y)∈R|f(x,y)|

Comment: I am asking which math working produces that term ( b/M)

Comment: You really need to look at the proof to see where the values are used.

Comment: Thanks but i am wondering how they come up writing  the interval |x-xo| <_ h = min(a,b/M). Where does b/M result from?

Answer (score 2):

Note that apriori the function $(t,x)\mapsto f(t,x)$ is defined around $(t_0,x_0)$, at least on a closed rectangle $[t_0-a,t_0+a]\times [x_0-b, x_0+b]$. You consider the Picard iterations 
$x_0(t)\equiv x_0$, $x_{n+1}(t)=x_0+\int_{t_0}^t f(t,x_n(s))ds$ for $n\ge 0$.  The condition $t\in [t_0-\alpha,t_0+\alpha]$ is to make sure that $x_{n+1}(t)$ does not fall out of the interval $[x_0-b,x_0+b]$ at any step $n$. If you know that  $|f(t,x)|$ is at most $M$ and the interval $[t_0,t]$ is of length at most $\frac{b}{M}$ then the value of the integral $\int_{t_0}^t f(t,x_n(s))ds$ has modulus at most $\frac{b}{M} \cdot M = b$, so we are still in business with $x_{n+1}$.